# What noun is appropriate to use in this sentence?

Tags: word-request

What noun is good to use in the following sentence instaed of ...

"I had many ups and downs throughout my life, but I considered each obstacle in my life as ... to become stronger and successful person in my life."

Comment: Usually I see "challenge" in contexts like this.

Comment: perhaps 'a step' could fit in ...

Comment: You are missing an "a" after become. Become a stronger and successful person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase I have heard generally is "stepping stone to success".You could also use the word "challenge" for eg:there are no problems in life,only challenges.

Answer (score 2):

*An opportunity* would probably be the most likely thing you'd find in that sort of context.